# C# generic class using reference types and nullable value types

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

I have an interesting problem. I'd like to create a generic class that can deal with both Reference types as well as `Nullable<T>` types. Basically I want something like:

```
public class ClassWithNull<T>
{
    public T varName = null;
}
```

Now this, of course, does not compile because not all types can be assigned null, namely non-nullable value types. But the problem is `Nullable<T>` is a value type, so simply adding `where T : class` doesn't help me. My generics-foo is not too strong, but I haven't been able to find any way to say that `T` must either be a reference type or a nullable value type.

The idea I have to solve this is to make `ClassWithNull<T>` an abstract class. I could then add two sub-classes, one to deal with reference types and one to deal with nullable value types. Then, a static factory method in the base class could use reflection to determine which sub-class ought to be constructed. Something like:

```
public static ClassWithNull<T> CreateClassWithNull<T>()
{
    StackTrace st = new StackTrace();
    Type type = st.GetFrame(1).GetMethod().GetGenericArguments()[0];
    if (!type.IsValueType)
    {
        return new ClassWithReferenceType<T>();
    }
    else if (type == typeof(Nullable))
    {
        return new ClassWithNullableValueType<T>();
    }
    else
    {
        throw new Exception("Must provide nullable type.");
    }
}
```

The problem here is that generics are resolved statically. If `ClassWithReferenceType<U>` expects `U` to be a reference type, then calling `new ClassWithReferenceType<T>()` in the factory method is a compilation error since `T` is not required to be a reference type. The compiler does not know about the run time check.

Any ideas about how to implement such a thing?

Comment: Note that `T x = null;` will only compile if `x` is nullable, but `T x = default(T)` and `x == null` will *always* compile (it just always returns false for non-nullable types).

Comment: In your code, `typeof(Nullable)` refers to another type than you think, namely a static class which is non-generic. Instead one can say `type.IsGenericType && type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>)`. An alternative in this specific case is `Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(type) != null`. Also, it looks like you can use `typeof(T)` instead of what you call `type`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about:

```
public class ClassWithNull<T>
{
    public T varName = default(T);
}
```

(Actually, you don't even need the assignment - you can just leave it to be the default value on construction. But you might want `default(T)` for local variables.)

That won't stop you from using it incorrectly with a non-nullable value type - but is that enough?

If that doesn't help you, I would suggest writing *two* static methods, like this:

```
public static ClassWithNull<T> CreateClassWithNullForClass<T> where T : class
{
    return new ClassWithReferenceType<T>();
}

public static ClassWithNull<T> CreateClassWithNullForNullable<T> where T : struct
{
    return new ClassWithNullableValueType<T>();
}
```

The field in `ClassWithNullableValueType` would be `Nullable<T>` - `T` would be the underlying type.

Now if you want overloads of the same method, that gets a little harder, particularly if you don't want to pass any parameters. It's *possible*, but [*really, really horrible*](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/11/02/evil-code-overload-resolution-workaround.aspx).

Comment: I don't think he's interested in default(T) as it can be not null in some cases. His intention is rather to allow only to assign null ("must either be a reference type or a nullable value type").

Comment: @Wiktor: `default(T)` is always the null value for any `T` which *has* a null value. But there's no constraint which will allow this to be expressed. See the rest of my answer for further options though...

Comment: Your edited answer contains just the solution I thought about.

Comment: Yeah, the first solution is not sufficient. However the second one is brilliant. I have no idea why having *two* factory methods never occurred to me. I'll accept this answer in three minutes (why does SO prevent the asker from accepting an answer within 10 mins?)

Comment: @WiktorZychla: Goodo. I think I'd probably still stick with the first approach if possible though :)

Comment: @jjoelson: It's so that others get a chance to add a good answer too. The first "well, it works" answer isn't necessarily the best one - sometimes someone will post a *better* answer a few minutes later. Maybe someone will do that in this case too :)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this instead:

```
public class ClassWithNull<T>
{
    private object varName_priv = null;

    public T varName {
        get { return (T)varName_priv; }
        set { varName_priv = value; }
    }
}
```

This works because every non-pointer type in C# is convertible to `object`, including value types.